# How to prevent overriding an object when setting an existing record id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One day I tried to fixed some data in rails console.

```
    Class Project
      belongs_to :user
    end

    Class User
      has_many :projects        
    end
```

Code is simple, I was meant to relate a project to one user this in rails console:

```
    user = User.find 31
    project = Project.find 99
    project.user_id = user.id
    project.save
```

However, I made a mistake:

```
    user = User.find 31
    project = Project.find 99
    project.id = user.id #!!!!!! I used #id instead of #user_id
    project.save
```

Because Project has a record with id == 31, so this action is equivalent to update project where id == 31.

Is there a way to prevent this kind of mistype-error?

Comment: As a best practice, I would recommend not ever modifying production data via the console. Even if it seems very small (like this), there's not a great way to audit what happened, roll back changes, or prevent mistakes. Instead, you can write rake tasks, get them reviewed by someone else, write tests for them, try them out on sample data locally, and then run them on the server, and this will reduce the likelihood of corrupting production data.

Comment: @carols10cents thanks for your suggestion, very good point :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you need/want to experiment in the rails console without this having any permanent effects on your data you can invoke it with

```
rails console --sandbox
```

all changes will be rolled back when you quit the console.